# Store sql output in a vba variable

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have an sql query which I want to store in a vba variable and then get the number of rows of the output.

I have the following:

```
Dim PortInfo As Variant
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim lStr As String

Dim LastRow     As Long

  strServer = "DB-01"
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & strServer & ";" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    cnn.Open ConnectionString

lStr = "SELECT [PORTINFOID],[PORTNAME] FROM [a].[dbo].[portinfo]"

rst.Open lStr, cnn

 If Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF Then
   For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
      PortInfo = PortInfo & rst.Fields(i).name & vbTab
           Next
       Do Until rst.EOF

      For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
      PortInfo = PortInfo & rst.Fields(i) & vbTab
           Next
             rst.MoveNext
    Loop
 End If
 rst.Close
MsgBox PortInfo
    LastRow = ???
```

With the above I get the following:

[image]

Firstly, I am not sure if the `PortInfo` variable should be `Variant`. And if it should be, how can I get the output to be in a column/row way so that I can get the number of rows of the resulting table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- The `PortInfo` variable can by of type `String`.
- The `strServer` variable is obsolete when using the server name in the connection string.
- The database can also be part of the connection string.
- When using `vbTab` as column separator, use `vbCrLf` as line separator.
- To count the rows, just increment the `LastRow` variable for each record.
- Do not use `New` when declaring a variable, because these can't be cleared.
- Clear the object variables in the end.
- Use `Option Explicit` in each Module to force yourself to declare all variables (like `i`).

For example, the code could look like this:

```
Dim PortInfo As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim lStr As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=DB-01;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=a;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
lStr = "SELECT [PORTINFOID],[PORTNAME] FROM [dbo].[portinfo]"

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open ConnectionString

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open lStr, cnn

With rst
    If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
        For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
            PortInfo = PortInfo & .Fields(i).Name
            If i < .Fields.Count - 1 Then
                PortInfo = PortInfo & vbTab
            Else
                PortInfo = PortInfo & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Do Until .EOF
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
            PortInfo = PortInfo & .Fields(i)
            If i < .Fields.Count - 1 Then
                PortInfo = PortInfo & vbTab
            Else
                PortInfo = PortInfo & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

End With

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

MsgBox PortInfo
MsgBox "This have been " & LastRow & " records.", vbInformation, "I'm done."
```

Comment: thanks! Another question, will I be able to access each entry of the `PortInfo` variable? The next goal is to have each entry in a dynamic checkbox of a userform. and I was thinking of doing it as `For i = 1 To LastRow
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = *here goes what I haven't figured out*
    chkBox.Left = 5
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
Next i`

Comment: Well... no. And for sure you will not create a checkbox for every column, will you? I suggest to save the respective values in an array (if you want to save the values for later reference), or create the dynamic checkbox list right from within the loop.